# jquery image border on click

Tags: image, border

Why doesnt this work?

```
$(".char").click(function() {
   $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");  
   });

<img class=char src=1.gif>
<img class=char src=2.gif>
```

I want it to highlight via border when I click one of the images.

Also I'd like only one to be highlighted at once but I guess I'll look at that after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use $(document).ready() - your current jquery code executes before the targeted html elements are available in the dom

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".char").click(function() {
        $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    });
});
</script>
```